# Custom sort issue using XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to sort the elements in XML based on custom sort requirement. First I need to sort based on 1st character in VerificationCode in the order of V,P,U,A,C,R. Then I need to sort based on numeric in the 2nd and 3rd characters.

The sample xml I am using is

```xml
<ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.org">
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>US</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>A42</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>CH</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>V54</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>IN</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>U14</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>MY</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>V84</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>MX</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>C34</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
</ns3:Response>
```

For the 1st level of sort I XSL I have is as below. But it is not doing anything.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:variable name="sortOrder1" select="'|V|P|U|A|C|R'" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Codes">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder1, concat('|', substring(ns0:VerificationCode,1,1), '|')))" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ns0:Response>
         <xsl:copy-of select="/ns0:Response"/>
      </ns0:Response>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the expected output

```xml
<ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.org">
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>MY</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>V84</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>CH</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>V54</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>IN</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>U14</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>   
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>US</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>A42</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
   <ns3:Codes>
      <ns3:Name>MX</ns3:Name>
      <ns3:VerificationCode>C34</ns3:VerificationCode>
   </ns3:Codes>
</ns3:Response>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `copy-of` on the root node if you want to apply templates, also simply match on that particular `Response` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ns0:Response">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="sortOrder1" select="'|V|P|U|A|C|R'" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Codes">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder1, concat('|', substring(ns0:VerificationCode,1,1), '|')))" data-type="number"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>          
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNxR, however, has a slightly different order than the one you have shown as the V54 value in the input is before the V84 one.

Comment: Added another sort to achieve it `<xsl:sort select="substring(ns0:VerificationCode/text(), 2)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>`

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out what you want. You can make your life easier by using multiple sort statements, only one template and none of these namespaces.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/Response">
      <xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'VPUACR'" />
      <Response>
        <xsl:for-each select="Codes">
          <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder, substring(VerificationCode/text(), 1, 1)))"/>
          <xsl:sort select="substring(VerificationCode/text(), 1)" data-type="number"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Response>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Fiddle here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAT)